# Calculus - Find parameters $A,B \in \mathbb R$ such that the function's derivative is $0$ as many times as possible

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

we are given the function $$f(x)=x+A\frac{x^2-2}{x}+B\frac{x^2-2}{x^3}$$ where $A,B$ are some parameters in $\mathbb R$.

We are asked to find the values of $A,B$ such that we have the most derivatives of $f$ when $x=\sqrt2$ are zero.

I'll try to explain a bit more thoroughly.

Find $A,B$ such that $f'(\sqrt2)=f''(\sqrt2) = ... = f^{(p)}(\sqrt2)=0$ such that $p$ is maximal. Also find $p$.

What I did:

I derived the function and got:

$$f'(x)=1+A\frac{x^2+2}{x^2}-B\frac{x^2+6}{x^4}$$

What I want to do is derive again, define $x=\sqrt2$, demand $f'(x)=f''(x)=0$ and that way I'll have 2 equations with 2 parameters, and I could solve for $A,B$ but that seems very difficult.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Your approach is fine.  I don't know a better one.  Taking one more derivative is not a bad mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it via the method suggested in the body of the question.

the solution is: $A=\frac{-5}{8}$, $B=\frac{1}{4}$, and $p=2$.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. However, in your solution in the question there should be "-6" in the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an error in the expression for derivative. It should be

$$f'(x)=1+A\frac{x^2+2}{x^2}-B\frac{x^2-6}{x^4}$$

Second, consider

$$g(x)=x^3f(x)=(1+A)x^4+(B-2A)x^2-2B$$

Since we assume $f'(\sqrt{2})=f''(\sqrt{2})=0$:

$$g'(\sqrt{2})=(3x^2f(x)+x^3f'(x))|_{x=\sqrt{2}}=6f(\sqrt{2})=6\sqrt{2}$$

$$g'(\sqrt{2})=(4(1+A)x^3+2(B-2A)x)|_{x=\sqrt{2}}=(8+4A+2B)\sqrt{2}$$

$$g''(\sqrt{2})=(6xf(x)+6x^2f'(x)+x^3f''(x))|_{x=\sqrt{2}}=6\sqrt{2}f(\sqrt{2})=12$$

$$g''(\sqrt{2})=(12(1+A)x^2+2(B-2A))|_{x=\sqrt{2}}=24+20A+2B$$

So, you get

$$2A+B=-1, 10A+B=-6$$

$$A=-5/8,B=1/4$$